# Do we welcome Operations Research questions?

Tags: discussion

[This post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/scheduling-algorithm-for-scheduling-life) has an Operations Research flavor. Although the author does not explicitly phrase the question in OR terms (and it might be a homework assignment), I think it's on-topic (contrary to some comments).  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

We do welcome questions on operations research that have a computational and/or scientific emphasis. I think the number of optimization questions on the site that have been answered supports that statement.

However, the post referenced in Deathbreath's question is not an operations research question, since it uses scheduling in the sense of computer science (i.e., task scheduling, not determining a schedule by solving an optimization problem). The [Completely Fair Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) algorithm is used for task scheduling in the Linux kernel; it isn't used to solve scheduling problems in the computational operations research setting (that I know of, anyway, working in a group that does operations research).

Comment: So you don't think there's an OR formulation of his problem?

Comment: There could be an OR formulation of the problem, but that's not what the original poster asked, and if you were to solve this as an optimization problem, it's not clear to me how it would be more effective than the existing algorithm.

Comment: If there is an OR description (and as I said, it might be homework), I think we should've encouraged a reformulation of the question before closing it. If it's homework, your reference might've been answer enough.

Comment: Questions that are closed can still be edited. Based on reading the question, I think the chances that it would be expressed as an operations research problem would be unlikely, especially since, as I said, solving it using an optimization problem would be inefficient compared to the existing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an information, there is now an [Operations Research Stack Exchange](https://or.stackexchange.com/). The first question there is dated May 30, 2019, so it is quite recent.

This doesn't automatically make OR questions off-topic here, but I guess the OR community will slowly concentrate on that site over time, and they will be able to provide better answers than we can, in many cases.